# Gnuplot: CSV and Date on X-Axis

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot cryptocurrency data which is stored in a CSV file.

This is what the CSV file looking at the moment:

```
Date,Total,XMR,ETH,BTC,BCH
2018-01-20 14:28:09,-48.31496473496111,-2.618473974057121,9.759254879456023,-32.73371338624,-22.72203225412001
2018-01-20 14:32:42,-48.70059864440001,-2.6060653245296663,9.414353657705647,-32.67846583748799,-22.830421140088
2018-01-20 14:35:22,-48.63036074628374,-2.5440902562853935,9.414353657705647,-32.67846583748799,-22.822158310216004
2018-01-20 14:39:31,-48.541251796683724,-2.5440902562853935,9.414353657705647,-32.58935688788797,-22.822158310216004
```

This is my gnuplot script so far:

```
set key inside bottom right
set title 'Revenues'
set datafile separator ','
set ylabel 'EUR'
set grid
plot for [col=2:5] "data.txt" using 0:col with lines lw 2 title columnheader
```

This is what the result looks like:

[image]

But as you can see in the first column, every data set has a date which I also want to use. It should appear as the x axis label in a shorter form (e.g. 18/20/01) and the axis should also scale correctly.

My approach was this:

```
set xtics rotate
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'
set format x "%d-%m"
set xdata time
plot for [col=2:5] "data.txt" using 0:col:xtic(1) with lines lw 2 title columnheader
```

...which results in...

[image]

As you can see, the label for the x axis is the correct column but it's neither the format I want nor it's scaled (mention that I changed the last date to 2019).

Can you tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: `plot for [col=2:5] "data.txt" using 1:col w l`

Comment: So simple but yet so helpful. It works now! Thank you very much! :) Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solved...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gnuplot start counting columns at `1`:

```
set datafile separator ","
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'
set format x "%d-%m"
set xdata time
plot for [col=2:5] "data.txt" using 1:col
```